Animation Parameters in Unity?


Does anyone know how to write a code that can change the animator parameters? I tried making something but the variables i made were separate from the ones in the animator window so obviously it didn't work. I'm just trying to get him to walk left and right. right now i have it so if Direction equals -1 he does the walk left animation and if it's equal to 1 he goes right. I want these values to change when the player presses a or d or the arrows but I just cant figure out how to connect them. This is what i tried doing i know it's not anywhere near what i have to do to get this to work but man am I lost. I borrowed code from a similar question that was asked here
It wouldnt let me copy and paste my code for some stupid reason so it's in a picture

Since they are direction ones, you would do it in either FixedUpdate() or Update(). You are right that the code vars are not related to the anim vars. Only the Set*() functions change the variables used as animation params. Also keep in mind that setting a value to a param (such as myAnimator.SetInt("Direction", Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") is only done once and does not bind it to the param. Meaning, if the axis changes, the anim param does not, unless you update it regularly. So your approach is right. The problem is your using axis, not keys (such as A or D).

Also, please post images only of environment (Visual Studio options, Unity Editor things such as Inspector properties, Scene View etc., directories), otherwise, post code as formatted text, not as images. Try using Input.GetKey("A") instead of Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"). Axis is for controller, joystick or mouse movement.
